# How to call cmd.exe from Python in Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cmd

I struggle calling cmd.exe from Python.
Here are two attemps so far:

```
  command = r'dir "D:\tmp 1\tmp 2" > "D:\tmp 1\tmp 2\dir.txt"'
  command = r'dir "D:"'
  print(command)
  status = subprocess.call(["cmd.exe", "/c", command])
  if status == 0:
    print("Command executed.")
  else:
    print("Error:", status)

def call_cmd_demo2():
  mycommand = r'cmd.exe dir "D:\tmp 1\tmp 2" > "D:\tmp 1\tmp 2\dir.txt"'
  mycommand = r'cmd.exe dir "D:"'
  print(mycommand)
  status = os.system(mycommand)
  if status == 0:
    print("Command executed.")
  else:
    print("Error:", status)
```

> command = r'dir "D:\tmp 1\tmp 2" > "D:\tmp 1\tmp 2\dir.txt"'

includes a redirection which happend to be another level of difficulties for reason beyond my skills. Reason why I started to get a simpler command to work.

The first version yields a syntax error on folder name (note that the command itself runs smoothly when pasted in a terminal)

The second version hangs.

Comment: Don't do any of this. Use the proper Python equivalents instead of starting a shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
    """
Module containing utility functions for executing system commands (Windows 10)
"""

from subprocess import run, CompletedProcess
from typing import Any
from utils import display_function_name

def execute(command: str) -> CompletedProcess:
  """
  Executes a DOS command in a console,
  Returns the result as a CompletedProcess object
  EXAMPLE:
  result: str = execute('echo Hello World').stdout
  print(result)

  :param command: The DOS command to execute
  :return: CompletedProcess object
  """
  result: CompletedProcess = run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True, encoding='cp850')
  return result


def execute_demo():
  for command in [
      r"""echo Hêllo to the ñew wörld""",
      r"""dir""",
      r"""dir "C:\" """]:
    print("\nCommand:" + command)
    print(f"Output:{execute(command).stdout}")
```

Comment: Please replace all occurrences of the word `DOS` by the word `Windows`. __DOS__ means __Disk Operating System__ which is something completely different than the __Windows Command Prompt__ which is a running instance of the *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` executing [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) like internal commands of `cmd.exe` and external commands in the Windows system directory and other executables. Thank you.

Comment: Notably, from Microsoft documentation, a lot of the commands are called DOS commands, and MS Windows does not actually have a true shell. Your point is valid but isn't absolute, I personally feel like it's wishy washy here... Would you like references?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look what happened in a simplified example (using `echo` instead of `dir` merely for debugging purposes):

```
import subprocess

#           ↓↓↓↓
command = r'echo "D:\tmp 1\tmp 2"'

# mixed `args`: unaccountably escaped inner double quotes
status = subprocess.call(["cmd.exe", "/c", command])
# \"D:\tmp 1\tmp 2\"

# string `args`: OK
status = subprocess.call("cmd.exe /c " + command)
# "D:\tmp 1\tmp 2"

# sequence `args`: OK
status = subprocess.call(["cmd.exe", "/c", "echo", r"D:\tmp 1\tmp 2"])
# "D:\tmp 1\tmp 2"

# sequence `args` (a complex case example): OK
import shlex
status = subprocess.call( shlex.split("cmd.exe /c " + command))
# "D:\tmp 1\tmp 2"
```

***Explanation***:

- [`subprocess.call(args, …`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call): … *the arguments shown above are merely some common ones. The full function signature is the same as that of the `Popen` constructor*…;
- [`subprocess.Popen(args, …`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen): … *`args` should be a **sequence of program arguments** or else a **single string** …*

**Note** It may not be obvious how to break a shell command into a sequence of arguments, especially in complex cases. [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) can illustrate how to determine the correct tokenization for `args`

Read [*Converting an argument sequence to a string on Windows*](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/subprocess.html#converting-an-argument-sequence-to-a-string-on-windows) as well…